# sql query to grab data from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql command like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT english from dic where english='"+e_word+"') " +
"Insert INTO dic VALUES('"+e_word+"',N'"+b_word+"') " +
"else " +
"UPDATE dic SET english='"+e_word+"',bangla=N'"+b_word+"' WHERE  english='"+e_word+"'",con);   


      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But i m getting error like

```
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
```

How can i solve this ?????

Comment: Generate the SQL outside of the `SqlCommand` constructor. Then view it in the debug window and tell us what the fully formatted SQL string is.

Comment: Are people maybe searching for `the dog's bowl` etc? which demonstrates a huge SQL injection hole (actually, I'd guess the word in question is something like `I'm`, `I'd`, etc)

Comment: That's what you get for not using parametrized queries.

Comment: In all seriousness, you need to read about SQL injection and parameters. Right now. Like: don't type another line of data-access code until you understand what is wrong with the code in the question, and how dangerous it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTFY:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT english from dic where english=@e_word)
Insert INTO dic (english, bangla) VALUES(@e_word,@b_word)
else UPDATE dic SET bangla=@b_word WHERE english=@e_word",con);   

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e_word", e_word);   
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b_word", b_word);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(actually, I'd usually do my upserts a bit different to that, but I didn't want to rewrite the entire thing)

Comment: @user2029069 in which location? the `@"..."` with *all* the SQL inside it is a *verbatim string literal* - it makes it easier to do mulit-line SQL, and you don't have to escape any characters except `"` (to `""`). The `@e_word` / `@b_word` are SQL parameters, who get their values from the two `AddWithValue` line. Note that SQL server uses the same syntax for parameters and local variables, so in the general case, `@foo` could also be a local variable. In *this* case, they are parameters.

Comment: I am using sqlCeCommand.But above this i am getting error.@Marc Gravell

Comment: @user2029069 does CE not support parameters? What specific error are you getting now?

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]